# Moment js handle zulu date time

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have problem retriving data from an api and display it in local time.

API print to me zulu datetime `2021-11-12T14:30:29.000000Z` I've tried varius soluton to transform it to Europe/Rome gtm but anyone worked, considering olso DST..

```
moment(d.acktime, "YYYYMMDDHHmmss").utcOffset('Europe/Rome').format("HH:mm");

moment(d.acktime, "YYYYMMDDHHmmss").tz("Europe/Rome").format("HH:mm");
```

The data displayed is always the zulu tume coming form api.. any ideas??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moment will [parse](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/) an ISO 8601 without specifying a format:

> When creating a moment from a string, we first check if the string matches known [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats, we then check if the string matches the [RFC 2822 Date time](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2822#section-3.3) format before dropping to the fall back of `new Date(string)` if a known format is not found.

Just make sure you use the moment-timezone (with data) library.

```js
const d = { acktime: '2021-11-12T14:30:29.000000Z' };

const formatted = moment(d.acktime).tz('Europe/Rome').format('HH:mm');

console.log(formatted); // 15:30 (Rome is GMT+1)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.34/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
```

Moment is [EOL](https://github.com/moment/momentjs.com/blob/master/docs/moment/-project-status/00-intro.md), so I recommend [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/) as an alternative. It is created by the same developers. Setting the timezone is also easier and does not require additional plugins and libraries. See ["Time zones and offsets"](https://github.com/moment/luxon/blob/master/docs/zones.md) for more information.

```js
const { DateTime } = luxon;

const d = { acktime: '2021-11-12T14:30:29.000000Z' };

const formatted = DateTime.fromISO(d.acktime).setZone('Europe/Rome').toFormat('HH:mm');

console.log(formatted); // 15:30 (Rome is GMT+1)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/luxon/2.1.1/luxon.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Finally it work, the "YYYYMMDDHHmmss" override the Zulu time and moment take it as local, after some try, now .tz work as expected